# How to find the watershed for each outlet point and sum values within it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, network, watershed

I have the following files to work with:

1. Stream network of a basin;
2. Outlet points for each segment* of the network and
3. Points which represent water withdrawals along of the stream, which are not located in the stream, but near of segments.

*segment = a line with a start point and an outlet point.

My goal is to calculate the sum of withdrawals located upstream of each outlet points.

My first attempt was using model builder, iterating over each outlet point. For each of them, I delineated the watershed and calculated the sum using Zonal Statistics (summing withdrawals contained by the watershed). But it didn't work well because ArcGIS aren't calculating watershed properly. I do not know why...

I'm wondering if I can figure out how to select directly upstream watersheds each iteration, assuming I've already obtained a feature containing the watersheds for each segment.

NOTICE: I don't want to find the watershed for each segment. I want to find the watershed for each outlet point. That's more comprehensive.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that each withdrawal point is takes water from the closest point in the stream?

Comment: yes om_henners, It's safe. The goal is summing all withdrawals within the watershed related to each outlet stream.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that each withdrawal point is related to the closest stream segment, we can do the following:

1. Use the [split line at point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003w000000) tool to split the stream line into
   segments based on outlet points (depending on your data you may
   already have this). Make sure that each point has an ID, which
   should relate to stream order (see one method below for an example
   in `Python`).
2. Use the [generate near table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001n000000) tool to generate a table that will
   link your withdrawal points to the nearest stream segment. Check the
   only get closest checkbox so you only get one result for each point.
3. Join the withdrawal amout to the near table to associate with the
   segment IDs.
4. Use the [summary statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool to sum the withdrawal amount
   grouped by segment ID.
5. Join the output withdrawal sums to your stream segment, select those
   segments upstream from the point of interest, and sum the total
   withdrawals (again, see below for one way to do this).

And example of IDing the segments using Python.

```py
import arcpy

#Written assuming arcGIS 10
#Note this will require modification to run...

start_pts = {}
end_pts = {}

for segment in arcpy.SearchCursor("segmented_line"):
    start_pts[segment.SEGMENT_ID] = segment.SHAPE.getObject(0) #SHAPE returns an arcpy.Array
                                                               #object containing points for
                                                               #geom type line
    end_pts[segment.SEGMENT_ID] = segment.SHAPE.getObject(segment.SHAPE.count)

try:
    #cleanup as you can only have one cursor open at once, otherwise wackiness
    del segment
except:
    pass

rows = arcpy.InsertCursor("start_pts")
for start in start_pts:
    row = rows.newRow()
    row.SHAPE = start_pts[start]
    row.SEGMENT_ID = start
    rows.insertRow(row)

try:
    #more cleanup
    del row
    del rows
except:
    pass

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(start_pts, outlet_pts, "start_outlet_pts",
                           "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", match_option="WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",
                           search_radius="some metres")

arcpy.JoinField_management("segmented_line", "SEGMENT_ID", "start_outlet_pts", "SEGMENT_ID", "OUTLET_ID")

################################################################################
##Repeat for end_pts
################################################################################
```

Once I get a bit of time later I'll come back and update this answer with a bit of script to build a network using networkx to help sum the values...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice Om_henners! I'm thankful about that. I was wondering if once I have each segment containing the sum of nearest withdrawals I could calculate the accumulated sum from upstream to downstream of the network. Actually, segments have individual IDs but IDs are not related with the network order. So, this seems to me a barrier to figure out how to perform the accumulated sum...In other hand, unhappily, I couldn't understand well the python code.=/...I've tried python in another attempt, but it didn't work fine. Maybe model builder could be a good option. What do you think?

Comment: If there is no options to do that I don't discard using python code.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, model builder should work for the most part - the only bit would be getting the start and end points of the segments, which you don't need to do if you do as suggested by @Rayner above and use the flow accumulation tool on the weights calculated as above (generate near table and summary statistics are both in the analysis toolbox).

Answer (score 4):

The solution to your problem may be to use Infrastructure Network Editing, specifically the Flow Accumulation tool on the Infrastructure Reporting Toolbar.

You'll need at least a Standard (Editor) license to build a geometric network.  You'll also need to specify a weight.  At each point or line, Calculate Accumulation will add up all your upstream weights and store them in a field.

Google "Infrastructure Network Editing 10.0" or "Infrastructure Network Editing 10.1" to get the right version.  This only works with ArcGIS 10.0 and above.